# How to return data with filter inside a reference ObjectID in Nodejs Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to filter data inside my referenced object and return data according to it.
I have two main Model Property and Listing. Listing has an Object of Property and Property contains Object of many other models. I need to send data all data of listing where some parameters of Property are matched.
This is my schema for Property

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const slug = require('mongoose-slug-generator');
mongoose.plugin(slug);

const PropertySchema = Schema({
  propertyby: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
  },
  propertyName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 100,
  },
  propertySlug: {
    type: String,
    slug: 'propertyName',
    slug_padding_size: 2,
    unique: true,
  },
  propertyLocation: {
    address: {
      type: String,
    },
    city: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'city',
    },
    area: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'area',
    },

    zipCode: {
      type: String,
    },
    latitude: {
      type: String,
    },
    longitude: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  propertyCategory: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'propertycategory',
  },
  propertyType: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Resedential', 'Commercial', 'Industrial', 'Agricultural'],
    default: 'Resedential',
  },
  propertyFace: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      'Default',
      'North',
      'East',
      'South',
      'West',
      'South East',
      'South West',
      'North East',
      'North West',
    ],
    default: 'Default',
  },
  bedroom: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  masterBedroom: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  bathroom: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  attachedBathroom: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  balcony: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  hall: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  dining: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  floor: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  bikeParking: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  carParking: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  storeroom: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },
  guardRoom: {
    type: Number,
    default: '0',
  },

  roadWidth: {
    type: Number,
  },
  roadSizePostfix: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Feet', 'Meters'],
    default: 'Feet',
  },
  roadType: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Default', 'Paved', 'Gravelled', 'Stonized'],
    default: 'Default',
  },
  builtYear: {
    type: String,
  },
  carpetArea: {
    type: String,
  },
  carpetAreaPostfix: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      'Sq. Feet',
      'Sq. Meter',
      'Aana',
      'Ropani',
      'Paisa',
      'Daam',
      'Dhur',
      'Gaj',
      'Bigha',
      'Katha',
      'Dhur',
      'Acre',
    ],
    default: 'Aana',
  },
  areaCovered: {
    type: String,
  },
  areaCoveredPostfix: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      'Sq. Feet',
      'Sq. Meter',
      'Aana',
      'Ropani',
      'Paisa',
      'Daam',
      'Dhur',
      'Gaj',
      'Bigha',
      'Katha',
      'Dhur',
      'Acre',
    ],
    default: 'Aana',
  },
  amenities: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'amenities',
    },
  ],
  description: [
    {
      des: {
        type: String,
      },
      floorplan: [
        {
          floorcount: {
            type: String,
          },
          bedroom: {
            type: Number,
            default: '0',
          },
          masterbedroom: {
            type: Number,
            default: '0',
          },
          balcony: {
            type: String,
          },
          hall: {
            type: Number,
            default: '0',
          },
          bathroom: {
            type: Number,
            default: '0',
          },
          attachedBathroom: {
            type: Number,
            default: '0',
          },
          dining: {
            type: Number,
            default: '0',
          },
        },
      ],
      nearestAttraction: [
        {
          attractionName: {
            type: String,
          },
          description: {
            type: Number,
            default: '0',
          },
          latitude: {
            type: String,
          },
          longitude: {
            type: String,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  images: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'media',
    },
  ],
});
PropertySchema.set('timestamps', true);
module.exports = Property = mongoose.model('property', PropertySchema);
```

And this is my Schema for Listing

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PropertyListingSchema = Schema({
  property: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'property',
  },
  listedby: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
  },
  listPrice: {
    type: String,
  },
  listPriceUnit: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      'Onetime',
      'Per Month',
      'Per Day',
      'Per Annual',
      'Per Sq. Feet',
      'Per Sq. Meter',
      'Per Aana',
      'Per Ropani',
      'Per Dhur',
      'Per Gaj',
      'Per Katha',
      'Per Acre',
      'Expense Sharing',
    ],
  },
  listType: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Buy', 'Rent', 'Lease', 'Share'],
  },
  contactNumber: [
    {
      type: String,
    },
  ],

  specialNote: {
    type: String,
  },

  numOfViewers: {
    type: String,
  },
});
PropertyListingSchema.set('timestamps', true);
module.exports = PropertyListing = mongoose.model(
  'propertylisting',
  PropertyListingSchema
);
```

What I want to do now is run find on Listing with conditions like sending data when city of property matches the query data I send.
For example, I am trying to filter out data if the name matches like,

```
var getallListing = await PropertyListing.find(query)
        .sort({
          createdAt: -1,
        })
        .limit(limit)
        .populate({
          path: 'property',
          match: {
            propertyName: 'edfcvgb',
            'propertyLocation.city': '5fc5fe1655257c4dd4af2b16',
          },
        })
```

The condition is working perfectly but it is returning all the listing and sending null in the property field of listing where the condition is not matched.